# Class calls attribute from wrong file

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, attributeerror

Error I am getting -
AttributeError: 'User_input_responses' object has no attribute 'screen'.
I believe in my Ship() file the  self.screen = game.screen is incorrectly looking into User_input_responses instead of looking into Alien_Invasion for access to screen. Not sure how to fix?

Main File -

```
import pygame 
from ship_movement import User_input_responses
from settings import Settings
from ship_test import Ship

class Alien_Invasion:


    def __init__(self):
        
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        #screen
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width , self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption(("Alien Invader"))
        self.bg_color = self.settings.bg_color

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.movement = User_input_responses()
  

            
    def update_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()





    def game(self):
        while True:
            self.movement.user_input_reactions()
            self.ship.ship_movement()
            self.update_screen()
            self.clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_launcher = Alien_Invasion()
    game_launcher.game()
```

File Calling Attribute -

```
import pygame 
from settings import Settings

class Ship:

    def __init__(self, game):
        
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
```

File Giving the Error

```
import pygame
import sys
from ship_test import Ship

class User_input_responses:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        



    def user_input_reactions(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.keydown(event)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self.keyup(event)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User_input_responses:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ship = Ship(self)
```

The `__init__` method of the `User_input_responses` class declares a `Ship` object and passes itself as the argument.

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = game.screen
```

And the `__init__` method of the `Ship` class expects the `game` argument to have a `screen` attribute.

But `game` is an instance of `User_input_responses`, which does not have a `screen` attribute.

Comment: i believe `Alien_Invasion` class does that as well and does have the `screen` attribute. When i remove `self` from `self.ship = Ship()` to not pass itself i get another error.`TypeError: Ship.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'game'`

Comment: @Wade Creating an instance of `Ship` requires that you pass an argument.  So yes, if you remove that argument, you will get an error.  I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Wade _i believe Alien_Invasion class does that as well_ Yes it does, but it works in that case, because that class **does** have a screen attribute.  The `Ship` class does **not** have a screen attribute, so you get an error.

Comment: @Wade It feels like you're trying to argue with me, saying that my answer is wrong.

Comment: So what your saying is that since `Ship()` requires an arugement to be passed & the fact that the arugement's attribute `screen` is used in `Ship`  that i cannot create an instance of `Ship()` and use its attributes without having `screen` defined?  If I add a requirement of a arguement into `User_input_responses` then pass _Alien_invasion_ into it and created  replicated `sceen` attribute would this work? My logic is if i give _User_input_responses_ access to _Alien_Invasion_ `screen` attribute then when _Ship_ calls for it it would work?

Comment: @Wade Yes you can create an instance of `Ship`, as long as the argument you pass to it has a `screen` attribute.

Comment: Im not trying to sound like im aruging but rather gauging for understanding. I do 100%  believe you are correct. Thanks i will try that change.